# Custom versioning of Jar in maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I want to create versioning structure folder for maven project in .m2

Below changes I have made in pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.XXXXXX.cm</groupId>
<artifactId>state-node</artifactId>
<version>1.5.0/1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>state-node</name>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build
```

Output:

```
.m2\repository\com\XXXXXX\cm\state-node\1.5.0\1.0\state-node-1.5.0\1.0.jar
```

Expected Output :

```
 .m2\repository\com\XXXXXX\cm\state-node\1.5.0\1.0\state-node-1.5.0.jar
```

1.5.0 is my dependency version and 1.0 is my project version. 
Project requirement is, If I use dependency (1.5.0) to build same project then jar folder structure should be in my .m2 folder 1.5.0\1.0\state-node-1.5.0.jar, 
If We do some modification in my project with same version of dependency then jar folder structure should be in  .m2 folder 1.5.0\2.0\state-node-1.5.0.jar 
We will manually update version 1.0 to 2.0 in pom.xml in case we do some modification

How I can achieve this.

Comment: `<version>1.5.0/1.0</version>` should be `<version>1.5.0</version>`

Comment: Remove the /1.0?  I think more detail might help.

Comment: @DKAnsh : 1.5.0 is my dependency version and 1.0 is my project version. Reason  to achieve this If I use dependency (1.5.0) to build same project then jar in my .m2 folder 1.5.0\1.0\state-node-1.5.0.jar, If I do some modification with same version of dependency then my project jar should be in my .m2 folder 1.5.0\2.0\state-node-1.5.0.jar

Comment: Avoid this. Using a version number with a / in it will most certainly break things in an unexpected way. Playing with the folder structure in .m2 is even worse. Just stick with usual version numbers. I do not understand your meaning of "dependency version" and "project version", but if you really need two numbers, use a version like 1.5.0-1 and 1.5.0-2.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not use version like this. You should use like `<version>1.5.0</version>`

But if you still want to use the same and just want to modify the jar file name than you can use below solution:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>myJar</finalName>                   
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Or For Maven >= 3

`<build>
   <finalName>WhatEverYouLikey</finalName>
 </build>`

Comment: First don't use such old versions of the plugins and furthermore the finalName will only define the name for the target directory but not what's being installed/deployed. This can't be changed.